# Multiple level grouping in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report with the 4 columns,

```
       ColumnA|ColumnB|ColumnC|ColumnD
Row1      A1     B1      C1       D1        
Row2      A1     B1      C1       D2        
Row3      A1     B1      C1       D1       
Row4      A1     B1      C1       D2       
Row5      A1     B1      C1       D1
```

I did like grouping based on the 4 columns, but i got output with space for every row.

But here in this report i would like to get the ouput as,

```
       ColumnA|ColumnB|ColumnC|ColumnD
Row1      A1     B1      C1       D1        
Row2      A1     B1      C1       D2        
<-------------an empty space ----------->
Row3      A1     B1      C1       D1       
Row4      A1     B1      C1       D2       
<-------------an empty space ----------->
Row5      A1     B1      C1       D1
```

How can i achieve the above output?

Comment: How does row 3 link to row 2, and row 5 to row 4? These are the columns that need to indented, based off the preceeding rows, so howdo you decide which rows are indented?

Answer (score 0):

A standard group by would sort the record like this:

```
       ColumnA|ColumnB|ColumnC|ColumnD
Row1      A1     B1      C1       D1        
Row3      A1     B1      C1       D1       
Row5      A1     B1      C1       D1
Row2      A1     B1      C1       D2        
Row4      A1     B1      C1       D2
```

Since you don't have a standard grouping, another approach may work. You basically want a blank line after the D2 value. This will only work if you always have D2 values at the end of a group.

Create a new blank detail section under the main section

```
Detail one
    A1     B1      C1       D1 
Detail two 
  <blank>
```

Then put a conditional suppress expression on detail two

```
ColumnD <> "D2"
```

Then whenever D2 is present the blank detail section will be displayed.

Comment: Hi Dj, thanks for the info! but i need the output in such the way i specified, like the value should be grouped based on the value in Column D as D1, D2 and another group with D1, D2 and at last the D1 should be grouped alone. Will it be possible to implement it?

Comment: See edit - it may need some tweaking depending on your data but the general concept should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Formula instead of a field Value for grouping.

```
select Column4 <br>
case D1 : "Group1"<br>
  case D2 : "Group2"<br>
  case D3 : "Group3"<br>
  case D4 : "Group3"<br>
  case D5 : "Group3"<br>
  case D6 : "Group4"<br>
default "Group5"<br>
```

Is that your problem ?

The blank lines can be generated as Group Footer.